# Find and replace text string with only parts of the existing string

Tags: vb.net

I have a .txt file that is formatted like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
|Order Number|PegReqOrNo  |Loc |Product Number    |OrdSrtTime|OrdEndTime|Prod. Time|Reqmt Time|OrdSrtDate|OrdEndDate|Comp. Date|Reqmt Date|     Date Var.|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
|000105812778|            |0002|10000347          |10:03:50  |19:37:43 |19:37:43  |00:00:00  |08/02/2016|02/16/2022|02/16/2022|          |  0/00:00:00|
|000106805034|4200252838  |0002|H827080082GAAZ    |13:43:25  |08:30:04 |08:30:04  |15:00:00  |02/18/2020|09/02/2020|09/02/2020|08/24/2020|   8/17:30:04-|
```

I am looking to  change the strings with pattern `##:##:##`  in the `date var.` column, the last on the right. I want to retain the value in front of the `/` and the `-` at the end, if there is one.

The two examples from the data above are `0/00:00:00` and `8/17:30:04-`, thus I want to retain `0` and `-8` respectively.

Comment: You could use Regular Expressions and create a pattern that requires the values to be at the end of the line (meaning there must be 13 times the symbol '|' before it (if i counted correctly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your strange request you can use as follows. I hope I well understood

```
Private Sub AdjustMyData()
    Try
        Dim allLines As IEnumerable(Of String) = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\YourUser\Desktop\test\test.txt")

        Dim data As List(Of String) = (From elemet In allLines).Select(Function(linea As String)
                                                                           If linea.Contains("|") Then
                                                                               Dim parts = linea.Split(CChar("|"))
                                                                               Dim newLinea = (From part In parts
                                                                                               Where part IsNot Nothing
                                                                                               Where part Like "*#/##:##:##*").Select(
                                                                                               Function(s As String) As String
                                                                                                   If s Is Nothing OrElse s.Length = 0 Then Return ""
                                                                                                   linea = linea.Replace(s, "~")
                                                                                                   Dim numerisS As String = CStr(IIf(s.Contains("-"), "-", "")) & Trim(s.Remove(s.IndexOf("/")))
                                                                                                   Return Space(s.Length - numerisS.Length) & numerisS
                                                                                               End Function).ToList.FirstOrDefault
                                                                               Return Strings.Replace(linea, "~", newLinea)
                                                                           End If
                                                                           Return linea
                                                                       End Function).ToList


        IO.File.WriteAllLines("C:\Users\YourUser\Desktop\test\testFinal.txt", data.ToArray)

    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub
```